Azure pipeline error "The report file pattern '/home/vsts/work/1/s/**/coverage.cobertura.xml' found no matching files."
I'm working on a testing pipeline on Azure Devops.
I've got an error but I don't know how to fix it.
The error is "The report file pattern '/home/vsts/work/1/s/**/coverage.cobertura.xml' found no matching files."
Here is my yaml file:
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk 8.x'
  inputs:
    version: 8.x

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet restore'
  inputs:
    command: restore

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet test'
  inputs:
    command: test
    arguments: '--collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Install ReportGenerator'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: tool
    arguments: 'install --global dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool'

- task: Palmmedia.reportgenerator.reportgenerator-build-release-task.reportgenerator@5
  displayName: ReportGenerator
  inputs:
    reports: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/coverage.cobertura.xml' #Here is incorrect.
    targetdir: '$(Build.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/CodeCoverage'

- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  displayName: 'Publish code coverage results'
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: Cobertura
    summaryFileLocation: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/Cobertura.xml'

I'm not sure what goes worng here. Anyone has any idea?


"The report file pattern '/home/vsts/work/1/s/**/coverage.cobertura.xml' found no matching files."

The cause of the issue is that the coverage.cobertura.xml file will be created in the folder:$(Agent.TempDirectory) instead of $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
To solve this issue, you can set the path:
$(Agent.TempDirectory)/**/coverage.cobertura.xml

For example:
- task: Palmmedia.reportgenerator.reportgenerator-build-release-task.reportgenerator@5
  displayName: ReportGenerator
  inputs:
    reports: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)/**/coverage.cobertura.xml' 
    targetdir: '$(Build.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/CodeCoverage'

For more detailed info, you can refer to my another answer: Visualize .net core code coverage directly in Azure Pipelines
